# error MSB6006: "codesign" exited with code 1 while build on appcenter

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center

I am using xamarin forms for application development. I am using appcenter for taking build for iOS and android also. When i am trying to take build on iOS, i am getting the following error on appcenter:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(1912,3): error MSB6006: "codesign" exited with code 1. [/Users/runner/work/1/s/MyPrj/MyPrj.iOS/MyPrj.iOS.csproj]
```

Can anyone trying to solve this issue

Comment: Could you build it locally ?

Comment: yes Leo, I can build

Comment: Did you try to delete the bin an obj files,and cleaned the solution,then rebuild it.

Comment: yes. But it is not working